# gnu parallel not recognize user-defined functions

Tags: function, user-defined-functions, gnu, gnu-parallel

I cannot get the gnu parallel function to implement a custom function that I built.

My function is:

```
function run_cuffLinks() {
    inputBAM="${HOME}/Analyses/P_miniata/CleanUpPipeline/TH_${1}/${1}.realigned.bam"
    if [[ ! -f $inputBAM ]]; then echo -e "$inputBAM could not be found\nexit 1" ; fi 
    WORKING_DIR="${HOME}/data/CuffLinks/TH_$1"
    if [[ ! -d $WORKING_DIR ]]; then mkdir -p $WORKING_DIR; fi

    REF="${HOME}/ReferenceSequences/GATK_pmin.scaf.fa"
    if [[ ! -f $REF ]]; then echo -e "$inputBAM could not be found\nexit 1" ; exit 1; fi 

    GTF_FILE="${HOME}/ReferenceSequences/genes.sorted.gff3"    
    if [[ ! -f $GTF_FILE ]]; then echo -e "$inputBAM could not be found\nexit 1" ; exit 1; fi 

    cufflinks \
    --output-dir $WORKING_DIR \
    --num-threads 2 \
    --frag-len-mean 100 \
    --GTF-guide $GTF_FILE \
    --frag-bias-correct $REF \
    -L "HH" \
    $inputBAM ;
}
```

When I enter:

```
parallel --no-notice -j+2 run_cuffLinks {} ::: sample1 sample2 sample3
```

I get the output:

```
/bin/bash: run_cuffLinks: command not found
/bin/bash: run_cuffLinks: command not found
/bin/bash: run_cuffLinks: command not found
```

If I include a '$' symbol in front of the function name, I get:

```
/bin/bash: sample1: command not found
/bin/bash: sample2: command not found
/bin/bash: sample3: command not found
```

I have also tried using the -pipe --recend and --rrs options, but without a positive result. 
Is GNU parallel not able to process user-defined functions?

Answer (score 3):

You do not write whether you have walked through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). In that it shows that you must `export -f` the function, and since you do not write that, I believe you might have forgotten that:

```
export -f run_cuffLinks
parallel ...
```

Since version 20180522 you can also use `env_parallel`:

```
env_parallel --session
[define functions and variables here that you want parallel to see]
# Use env_parallel like you would parallel
env_parallel run_cuffLinks ...
```

PS: Use --bibtex once to avoid --no-notice in the future.